# Tkinter entry text not passing to send.keys() in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

I have been trying to create a program that will run through a loop and pull entries from a tkinter GUI and pass it send.keys() command. However, when I use this loop, it will pass the variable name of p1.get() instead of pulling whatever that variable is equal to. I have run code where I set it up as a normal list and pull from that by using "test" and it will work but it will not work how it is set up now. I also read that some people would have to send empty text to send.keys() first but this also did not work. I am fairly new to both python and selenium so I could have made a simple mistake and overlooked it but any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.muted = True
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Matt/Downloads/chromedriver', options=options)

app = tk.Tk()

p1 = tk.StringVar()
p2 = tk.StringVar()

entryPlayer1 = tk.Entry(app, textvariable = p1, width=20)
entryPlayer1.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=tk.N)
entryPlayer2 = tk.Entry(app, textvariable = p2, width=20)
entryPlayer2.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=tk.S)

def click():
    for i in range(1, 2):
        pID = ("p" + str(i) + ".get()")
        browser.get("https://www.espn.com/")
        time.sleep(1)
        srch_btn = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="global-search-trigger"]')
        srch_btn.click()
        srch_bar = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="global-search"]/input[1]')
        srch_bar.send_keys(pID)

SubmitButton = tk.Button(app, text = 'Submit', command = click)
SubmitButton.grid(column=3, row=5, pady=10, padx = 10)

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `for i in range(1, 2)` will loop only one time with `i = 1` because `range(a, b)` includes only from `a` to `b-1`.

Second, it should be `pID = eval("p" + str(i) + ".get()")`.  But using `eval()` is not recommended.  Try using list to hold the variables, for example:

```
# if `my_vars` holds the variables
for i in range(2):
    pID = my_vars[i].get()
    ...
```